# Only fire Material Autocomplete when more than 2 chars have been entered

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I have a material autocomplete component that is working pretty well. I've shamelessly cobbled it together from various online examples. I am struggling to figure out how to have the search only fire when 2 or more chars are entered.

```
assignSearchAutocomplete(){
    this.acCtrl.valueChanges
        .pipe(
            debounceTime(500),
            tap(() => {
                this.acErrorMsg = "";
                this.acFilteredItems = [];
                this.acIsLoading = true;
            }),
            switchMap(value => this.svcGetFacetGql.watch({ name: ".*" + value + ".*", label: this.facetLabel, options: { fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network' } })
                .valueChanges
                .pipe(
                    tap(() => {
                        this.acIsLoading = false
                    }),
                )
            )
        )
        .subscribe(response => {
            if (response['data'] == undefined) {
                this.acErrorMsg = response['Error'];
                this.acFilteredItems = [];
            } else {
                this.acErrorMsg = "";
                this.acFilteredItems = response['data']['Facet'];
            }
        });
}
```

I've tried inserting an if statement and using a ternary operator :? but can't get it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out those values, where the string is empty or too short.

```js
assignSearchAutocomplete(){
    this.acCtrl.valueChanges
        .pipe(
            // new part
            filter(value => value && value.length >=2),
            // end of new part
            debounceTime(500),
            tap(() => {
                this.acErrorMsg = "";
                this.acFilteredItems = [];
                this.acIsLoading = true;
            }),
            // ...
        )
        .subscribe(response => {
            if (response['data'] == undefined) {
                this.acErrorMsg = response['Error'];
                this.acFilteredItems = [];
            } else {
                this.acErrorMsg = "";
                this.acFilteredItems = response['data']['Facet'];
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you try with a `filter` ?

```js
this.acCtrl.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    filter(value => value.length > 2),
    tap(() => {
    ...
    }
  );
```

Comment: Thanks - I accepted the other purely as you both had the same answer so I accepted the first, Thanks for replying.